# My Character keeps clipping into other bodies

Tags: java

I am making a 2D platformer in Java, and I am struggling with the collision detection. It mostly works, but whenever I land on a platform, the Character keeps moving down a few pixels. My code is hosted at [github](https://github.com/ethanf108/Platf). The classes that are related to this problem are `World.java` and `GameCharacter.java`
my collision check code(runs on infinite loop):

```
void collisionCheck() {
        for (GameCharacter gc : Characters) {
            gc.canJump = false;
            gc.canWallJump = false;
        }
        for (Platform g : Levels.get(Level)) {
            Rectangle tmprect = ((Rectangle) g.clone());
            tmprect.grow(RectScale, RectScale);
            for (GameCharacter gc : Characters) {
                if (gc.intersects(tmprect)) {
                    if (g.x + RectScale > gc.gx + gc.width) {
                        gc.isLeft = true;
                        gc.isMiddleX = false;
                    } else if (g.x + g.width < gc.gx + RectScale) {
                        gc.isLeft = false;
                        gc.isMiddleX = false;
                    } else {
                        gc.isMiddleX = true;
                    }
                    if (g.y + RectScale > gc.gy + gc.height) {
                        gc.isTop = true;
                        gc.isMiddleY = false;
                    } else if (g.y + g.height < gc.gy + RectScale) {
                        gc.isTop = false;
                        gc.isMiddleY = false;
                    } else {
                        gc.isMiddleY = true;
                    }
                    if (gc.isMiddleX && gc.isMiddleY) {
                        if (gc.isTop) {
                            gc.gmy = 0;
                            gc.gy -= 1;
                        } else {
                            gc.gmy = 0;
                            gc.gy += 5;
                        }/*
                        if (gc.isLeft) {
                            gc.gmx = 0;
                            gc.gx -= 1;
                        } else {
                            gc.gmx = 0;
                            gc.gx += 1;
                        }*/
                    } else if (gc.isMiddleY) {
                        if (gc.isLeft) {
                            if (gc.gmx > 0) {
                                gc.gx -= 1;
                                gc.gmx = 0;
                            }
                        } else if (gc.gmx < 0) {
                            gc.gmx = 0;
                            gc.gx += 1;
                        }
                    } else if (gc.isMiddleX) {
                        if (gc.isTop) {
                            if (gc.gmy > 0) {
                                gc.gmy = 0;
                            }
                        } else if (gc.gmy < 0) {
                            gc.gmy = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    if (gc.isTop && gc.isMiddleX) {
                        gc.canJump = true;
                    }
                    if (g.Props.contains("w") && gc.isMiddleY) {
                        gc.canWallJump = !gc.isMiddleX;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(CollisionDelay-1);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.err.println("ERROR");
        }
    }
```

My character update(runs on separate thread):

```
public void update() {
    ScreenX=world.Levels.get(world.Level).xs;
    ScreenY=world.Levels.get(world.Level).ys;
    if (gy >= ScreenY - (height + 10)) {
        gmy = 0;
        canJump = true;
        gy = ScreenY - (height + 10);
    } else if (gy < 0) {
        gmy = 0;
        gy = 0;
    } else {
        gmy += 2;
    }
    if (gx + width > ScreenX) {
        gx = ScreenX - width;
        gmx = 0;
    } else if (gx < 0) {
        gx = 0;
        gmx = 0;
    } else if (RightKeyPressed) {
        gmx += 0.07;
    } else if (LeftKeyPressed) {
        gmx -= 0.07;
    }
    if (SpacePressed && (canJump || canWallJump)) {
        if (canWallJump && !canJump) {
            if (isLeft && RightKeyPressed) {
                gmx = -6;
                gmy = -220.0;
            } else if (!isLeft && LeftKeyPressed) {
                gmx = 6;
                gmy = -220.0;
            }
        } else {
            gmy = -220.0;
        }
    }
    gmx *= 0.97;
    gx += gmx;
    gy += gmy / 70;
    x = (int) gx;
    y = (int) gy;
    try {
        Thread.sleep(world.getSpeed());
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your question.

Comment: @computerfreaker ok thanks!